# How to upgrade zabbix 3.2 to 5.4 in rhel 7.2

Tags: zabbix

I need to upgrade zabbix server to rhel7.2 but is not possible, when I try to install the package of the version 5.4 rpm say: "el paquete zabbix-release-5.4-1.el8.noarch ya está instalado
el archivo /etc/yum.repos.d/zabbix.repo de la instalación de zabbix-release-5.4-1.el8.noarch entra en conflicto con el archivo del paquete zabbix-release-3.4-2.el7.noarch
el archivo /etc/yum.repos.d/zabbix.repo de la instalación de zabbix-release-5.4-1.el8.noarch entra en conflicto con el archivo del paquete zabbix-release-5.0-1.el7.noarch"

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile it yourself, because Zabbix 5.4 doesn't have official packages for RHEL 7, only RHEL 8. You are trying to install a `.el8.noarch` package on a RHEL 7, which is not good.

Also, latest RHEL 7 is 7.9, you should first upgrade RHEL and then upgrade Zabbix. Also, you should just reinstall a fresh RHEL 8 and switch over, because RHEL 7 is approaching EOL. Please note that Centos 8 is almost at EOL itself, but there's Centos 8 Stream available.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/installation/install_from_packages/rhel_centos